# confusion regarding erlang maps, lists and ascii

Tags: erlang

This code is an excerpt from this [book](http://www.amazon.in/Programming-Erlang-Software-Concurrent-World/dp/9351104672).

```
count_characters(Str) ->
    count_characters(Str, #{}).

count_characters([H|T], #{ H => N }=X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{ H := N+1 });
count_characters([H|T], X) ->
    count_characters(T, X#{ H => 1 });
count_characters([], X) ->
    X.
```

So,

```
1> count_characters("hello").
#{101=>1,104=>1,108=>2,111=>1}
```

What I understand from this is that, `count_characters()` takes an argument *hello*, and place it to the first function, i.e `count_characters(Str)`.

What I don't understand is, how the **string characters** are converted into ascii value without using `$`, and got incremented. I am very new to erlang, and would really appreciate if you could help me understand the above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In erlang the string literal `"hello"` is just a more convenient way of writing the list `[104,101,108,108,111]`. The string format is syntactic sugar and nothing erlang knows about internally. An ascii string is internally string is internally stored as a list of 32-bit integers.

This also becomes confusing when printing lists where the values happen to be within the ascii range:

```
io:format("~p~n", [[65,66]]).
```

will print

```
"AB"
```

even if you didn't expect a string as a result.

Comment: Yes, erlang has neither a character datatype nor a string datatype. The integer characters values are more generally unicode codepoints, and not just ascii values.

Answer (score 2):

As said previously, there is no string data type in Erlang, it uses the internal representation of an integer list, so

`"hello" == [$h,$e,$l,$l,$o] == [104|[101|[108|[108|[111|[]]]]]]`

Which are each a valid representation of an integer list.

To make the count of characters, the function use a new Erlang data type: a map. (available only since R17)

A map is a collection of key/value pairs, in your case the keys will be the characters, and the values the occurrence of each characters.

The function is called with an empty map:`count_characters(Str, #{})`.

Then it goes recursively through the list, and for each head `H`, 2 cases are posible:

- The character `H` was already found, then the current map `X` will match with the pattern `#{ H => N }` telling us that we already found `N` times `H`, so we continue the recursion with the rest of the list and a new map where the value associated to `H` is now `N+1`: `count_characters(T, X#{ H := N+1 }`.
- The character `H` is found for the first time, then we continue the recursion with the rest of the list and a new map where the key/value pair `H/1` is added: `count_characters(T, X#{ H => 1 })`.

When the end of the list is reached, simply return the map: `count_characters([], X) -> X.`